# Wordpress wp_ajax not called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to get my first AJAX Function working in Wordpress 4.3.

I have build an plugin named "calipso".
In the plugin there are the two files

calipso.php :

```
<?php
/**
* @package calipso
* @version 1.0
*/
/*
Plugin Name: calipso
Plugin URI: http://www.calipso.de
Description: Dieses  Plugin for Calipso-Projekt.
Author: Calipso
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.calipso.de
*/

function llv_integrates() {
    $plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_script('MyAjax',$plugin_url . 'MYajax.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0',false);

    $ajaxObjekt = array( 'ajaxURL' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script('MyAjax', 'ajaxObjekt', $ajaxObjekt);   
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'llv_integrates' );

function TEST_callback(){
    $anzahl= $_POST['anzahl'];
    //$anzahl = isset($_POST['anzahl']) ? $_POST['anzahl'] : '';

    $datei_handle=fopen("logmeInWPAnzahl.txt","a"); 
    fwrite($datei_handle, "Anzahl: ".$anzahl."\n"); 
    fclose($datei_handle);    
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_TEST_callback','TEST_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_TEST_callback','TEST_callback');
```

and MYajax.js :

```
function JStoPHP(){ 
    console.log("JStoPHP is called");
    console.log(ajaxObjekt.ajaxURL);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:ajaxObjekt.ajaxURL,  
        data: {action:'TEST_callback' , anzahl: "12315"},
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(respose) {
             console.log(respose);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
JStoPHP();
```

Expected operation: transfer of the variable 'Number' from the JavaScript function JStoPHP to via ajax called PHP function TEST_callback.

Currently the TEST_callback function seems to be not invoked. Where is my mistake?

Comment: change "TEST" to "TEST_callback" in your jquery.ajax function.

Comment: Thank you David. I have overlooked this when testing. Now I correct the action:'TEST_callback'. Unfortunately, that was not the solution.

Comment: Try adding success and error callbacks to the ajax call and log the response, like this:      `error: function(xhr, status, error) {}`
     `success: function(response) {}`

Comment: @xphan  I added the success and error callbacks and get this result:          <script>console.log ("add_ajax_actions is called");</script>      <script>console.log ("wp_ajax_");</script>

Comment: seems to be ok codewise, so there are a couple of things to check, 1. you are logging ajaxurl - is this the correct url? 2. you are adding the actions on init, there is actually no need to do this, so remove the function wrapper. Im not sure init is called in a ajax request, but a good way to test is echo something (you currently are not) (echo $datei_handle) within the php function to test. Have you tested fopen() outside of ajax? You have just provided a filename rather than a path so its in your plugin folder is the folder writable?

Comment: My console.log: `add_ajax_actions is called ` ->  `JStoPHP is called ` ->  `http:// XXX /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php ` ->  `<script>console.log ("add_ajax_actions is called");</script> `

Comment: well the function is being called so and its not a ajax error. Check your fopen function outside of ajax to see if thats working ok. Also remove datatype; json, its not needed for this

Comment: @David thank you. I will follow your suggestions and test it.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you for your help. The Code must be at the first place in my plugin to get working.

Comment: Please post  your own answer and accept it if your problem is solved. Do not put the word "solved" in the title. See also: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code must be at the first place in the plugin to get working.